# OpenGL draw with self defined buffer

Tags: c, opengl

I'm now using opengl3.3 and glfw to draw+show.
However, currently, OpenGL draws in its internal frame buffer.
I suppose it is "glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);"

I wonder if I can define a buffer by myself and let OpenGL draw in this buffer?
e.g.

```
GLuint ownbuffer[800*600*4]; // width:800, height:600, ARGB channel

// by setting some APIs to let OpenGL draw in the above buffer?
```

I read about FBO, my original thinking is that I can use it to draw in FBO buffer by filling the buffer address in the texture buffer.
However, it seems that it does not work. I get an all-zero buffer.
e.g.

```
    GLuint frameBuffer;
    glGenFramebuffers(1, &frameBuffer);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, frameBuffer);

    GLuint texColorBuffer;
    GLuint ownbuffer[800*600*4];
    glGenTextures(1, &texColorBuffer);
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE8);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texColorBuffer);

    glTexImage2D(
        GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, 800, 600, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, ownbuffer
    ); // by setting buffer here instead of fill in NULL

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

    glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, texColorBuffer, 0);
```

Moreover, is it possible to let glfw show our own buffer? e.g. ownbuffer mentioned above.

In this case, I don't need to dump buffer data into files for checking the result.

Answer (score 2):

> *I want opengl directly draws into the buffer I prepare (`ownbuffer`) ...*

Sorry, but that's not possible. OpenGL renders in the (default) framebuffer and you can't redirect that (or mirror) it to a CPU memory address.

---

You cannot attach a texture or render buffer to the default framebuffer. You have to create a named framebuffer object:

```c
GLuint fbo;
glGenFramebuffers(1, &fbo);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fbo);
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, texColorBuffer, 0);
```

and you can copy the pixels of the color plane from the default framebuffer (0)
into the named framebuffer with [`glBlitFramebuffer`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glBlitFramebuffer.xhtml):

```c
glBindFramebuffer(GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, fbo);
glBlitFramebuffer(0, 0, 800, 600, 0, 0, 800, 600, GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT, GL_NEAREST);
```

Anyway, now the data is still in the texture data store and not in your `ownbuffer`. The textures data store and the source data are not linked. [`glTexImage2D`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glTexImage2D.xhtml) just copies the data.
Instead of rendering to the default framebuffer, you can render to the named framebuffer directly (`glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fbo);`). In this case, however, nothing is drawn in the window at all.

---

If you just want to read data from the framebuffer, you need to use  [`glReadPixels`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glReadPixels.xhtml). `glReadPixles` can read the data directly into CPU memory or read it in a `GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER` buffer. You can use [Buffer Mapping](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Buffer_Object#Mapping) to access the data from the pixel buffer ([`glMapBuffer`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glMapBuffer.xhtml)). However, in either case it is necessary to call `glReadPixles` each time you want to get the current buffer data.

Comment: I got it! Thanks very much for your help.
BTW, may I ask if I call glReadPixles with PBO, to make sure the copy is done, should I call "glFenceSync(GL_SYNC_GPU_COMMANDS_COMPLETE, 0U);" before glMapBuffer?